# API Platform Logging Headers from requests

Tags: symfony, logging, symfony4, api-platform.com

I have an authentication issue on a production server, the issue is very likely to be non-code related but rather an IT configuration issue...

To prove this I would like to **check if API Platform receives the Authorization header** when trying to fetch data. I have not found anything about logs in the API Platform documentation. **What is the right way of logging API requests and their headers** using the Symfony logging systems, knowing that I don't have access to the actual controller code as it is purely configured using the APIRessource annotation on entities ?

*To be clear, everything works fine in local, I'm not looking for a solution to my problem here, just a clean way to change the log format or add logs to incoming request using API Platform.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a listener for the kernel.terminate event, that would be logging request and response data. Something like this.

**monolog.yaml**

```
monolog:
  handlers:
    request_log:
      type: rotating_file
      max_files: 90
      level: debug
      path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/request/%kernel.environment%.log'
      channels: request_log
```

**services.yaml**

```
App\EventListener\LogRequestAndResponseEventListener:
    tags:
        - { 'name': 'monolog.logger', 'channel': 'request_log' }
        - { 'name': 'kernel.event_listener', 'event': 'kernel.terminate', 'method': 'onKernelTerminate' }
```

**listener**

```
namespace App\EventListener;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\TerminateEvent;

class LogRequestAndResponseEventListener
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function onKernelTerminate(TerminateEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $response = $event->getResponse();

        $this->logger->info('data', [
            'route' => $request->getMethod() . ' ' . $request->getRequestUri(),
            'status' => $response->getStatusCode(),
            'request body' => $request->request->all(),
            'response' => json_decode($response->getContent(), true),
            'headers' => $request->headers->all(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got an error: 
Invalid service "App\EventSubscriber\LogRequestAndResponseEventListener": class "App\EventSubscriber\LogRequestAndResponseEventListener" does not exist.
Also i triple check that the file (and class name) is in the right place. If i comment the second tag in services, the error stops, but not logging.. no log file created at all. What could it be? Thanks!

Comment: @giannis.epp can you show your code? Did you change the service definition in the services.yaml?

Comment: @Ihor Kostrov i already fix it! I put your listener in the /src/EventListener/LogRequestAndResponseEventListener.php  and then i update the class path in services.yaml. There was no recognition in path /EventListener/LogRequestAndResponseEventListener.php (App\EventListener\LogRequestAndResponseEventListener). So, there are all ok! Thank you for your solution too! upvoting!